# External HDD detected, but not recognised. Cannot mount, cannot format, cannot do partition

Tags: hard-drive

I am new to ubuntu and this community. I have a seagate expansion external HD (1 TB) which needs rescue. Firstly it crashed sometime back. By then I could use some data recovery software to recover my data. But I was impatient for a data recovery process of 10 days and thus I unplugged the drive. Thereafter windows stop recognizing the drive. Quite recently I was researching online to find the drive might be recognized by ubuntu and thankfully it did. But the problem is that neither I can create a disk image, nor format it, nor do partitions. it doesn't mount. I have done extensive research to find out the exact cause of the error. Ran the dmesg command and have collected some information. The info relevant is as below:

```
[   33.024928] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   33.043698] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[   33.043701] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   33.043702] usb 2-1: Product: Expansion
[   33.043703] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Seagate 
[   33.043705] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: NA4AT906
[   33.055276] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   33.055796] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[   33.055897] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   33.057513] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   34.053914] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0219 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   34.054233] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   55.120163] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[   59.640823] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[   59.644262] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[   60.367518] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   61.380448] .ready
[   61.380624] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   61.380628] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[   61.380662] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   61.380673] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[   61.380709] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[   61.380722] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   61.381302] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   61.381304] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[   61.381317] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  116.391733] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 17min 55.120014s random time.
[  180.155884] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  180.172597] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  180.172601] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  180.172603] usb 2-1: Product: Expansion
[  180.172605] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  180.172607] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[  180.174591] scsi host5: uas
[  180.176468] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  180.176973] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  180.177288] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  181.178895] ................................................................................
[  261.140098] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  261.426865] .ready
[  261.586851] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  261.586854] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  261.706802] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  261.706806] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  261.794720] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  261.794723] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  261.834688] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[  261.834692] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  262.062590] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  262.062594] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  262.182519] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  262.182522] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  262.422368] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  275.958597] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  275.975347] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  275.975351] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  275.975353] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  275.975355] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  275.975356] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[  275.977125] scsi host6: uas
[  275.977598] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  275.978151] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  275.978258] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  276.977994] ...................................................................................................
[  376.245447] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  376.245528] sd 6:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[  376.245531] sd 6:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[  376.245554] ready
[  376.361931] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  376.361935] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  376.482049] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  376.482052] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  376.570129] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  376.570132] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  376.610165] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[  376.610169] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  376.842367] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  376.842370] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  376.962439] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  376.962442] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  377.162638] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  383.263500] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  383.280228] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  383.280232] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  383.280234] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  383.280236] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  383.280238] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[  383.282026] scsi host7: uas
[  383.283790] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  383.284411] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  383.284438] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  384.288132] ..............................
[  414.341158] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  414.426199] .ready
[  414.586320] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  414.586323] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  414.706355] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  414.706360] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  414.794375] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  414.794379] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  414.834391] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[  414.834395] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  415.062455] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  415.062458] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  415.182491] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  415.182495] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  415.382544] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  436.159245] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  436.175831] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  436.175834] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  436.175836] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  436.175837] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  436.175838] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[  436.177490] scsi host8: uas
[  436.178528] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  436.179064] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  436.179388] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  437.183342] ..ready
[  438.187867] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  438.187871] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 2048-byte physical blocks
[  438.401354] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  438.401359] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[  438.404691] usb 2-2: cmd cmplt err -71
[  438.404695] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event for disabled endpoint or incorrect stream ring
[  438.404698] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: @000000003fb70700 00000000 00000000 04000000 08078001
[  439.135787] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  439.136027] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[  439.136036] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Mode Sense(6) 1a 00 08 00 04 00
[  439.136109] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[  439.136119] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  439.363764] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  439.363767] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  439.483784] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  439.483787] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  439.723819] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  453.361652] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  453.378371] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  453.378373] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  453.378375] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  453.378376] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  453.378377] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: NA4AT906
[  453.380046] scsi host9: uas
[  453.380499] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  453.381082] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  453.381084] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  453.381695] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  453.842067] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  453.842071] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[  453.842272] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  453.853509]  sdb: sdb1
[  453.854847] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  501.001736] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  501.118525] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  501.153024] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  501.527014] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  501.543688] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  501.543690] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  501.543692] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  501.543693] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  501.543694] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: NA4AT906
[  501.545329] scsi host10: uas
[  501.546356] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  501.546876] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  501.547082] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  501.547085] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  501.547394] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  501.547397] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[  501.547554] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  503.618587]  sdb: sdb1
[  503.619863] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  513.448650] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  513.571824] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  513.604864] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  513.980307] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  513.996960] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  513.996962] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  513.996964] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  513.996965] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  513.996966] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: NA4AT906
[  513.998656] scsi host11: uas
[  513.999666] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  514.000116] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  514.000871] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  514.000873] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  514.001488] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  514.001492] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[  514.001638] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  516.080393]  sdb: sdb1
[  516.081744] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  516.947836] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[  516.948257] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  517.071106] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK[   33.024928] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   33.043698] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[   33.043701] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   33.043702] usb 2-1: Product: Expansion
[   33.043703] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Seagate 
[   33.043705] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: NA4AT906
[   33.055276] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   33.055796] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[   33.055897] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   33.057513] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[   34.053914] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0219 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   34.054233] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[   55.120163] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[   59.640823] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U1 failed.
[   59.644262] usb 2-1: Disable of device-initiated U2 failed.
[   60.367518] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   61.380448] .ready
[   61.380624] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   61.380628] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[   61.380662] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   61.380673] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[   61.380709] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[   61.380722] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   61.381302] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[   61.381304] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[   61.381317] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  116.391733] systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 17min 55.120014s random time.
[  180.155884] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  180.172597] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  180.172601] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  180.172603] usb 2-1: Product: Expansion
[  180.172605] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  180.172607] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[  180.174591] scsi host5: uas
[  180.176468] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  180.176973] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  180.177288] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  181.178895] ................................................................................
[  261.140098] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  261.426865] .ready
[  261.586851] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  261.586854] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  261.706802] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  261.706806] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  261.794720] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  261.794723] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  261.834688] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[  261.834692] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  262.062590] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  262.062594] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  262.182519] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  262.182522] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  262.422368] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  275.958597] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  275.975347] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  275.975351] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  275.975353] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  275.975355] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  275.975356] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[  275.977125] scsi host6: uas
[  275.977598] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  275.978151] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  275.978258] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  276.977994] ...................................................................................................
[  376.245447] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  376.245528] sd 6:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[  376.245531] sd 6:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Test Unit Ready 00 00 00 00 00 00
[  376.245554] ready
[  376.361931] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  376.361935] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  376.482049] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  376.482052] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  376.570129] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  376.570132] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  376.610165] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[  376.610169] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  376.842367] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  376.842370] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  376.962439] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  376.962442] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  377.162638] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  383.263500] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  383.280228] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  383.280232] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  383.280234] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  383.280236] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  383.280238] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[  383.282026] scsi host7: uas
[  383.283790] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  383.284411] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  383.284438] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  384.288132] ..............................
[  414.341158] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  414.426199] .ready
[  414.586320] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  414.586323] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  414.706355] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  414.706360] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  414.794375] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  414.794379] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 00 00 00
[  414.834391] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[  414.834395] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  415.062455] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  415.062458] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  415.182491] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  415.182495] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  415.382544] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  436.159245] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  436.175831] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  436.175834] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  436.175836] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  436.175837] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  436.175838] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 2HC015KJ
[  436.177490] scsi host8: uas
[  436.178528] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  436.179064] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  436.179388] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  437.183342] ..ready
[  438.187867] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  438.187871] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 2048-byte physical blocks
[  438.401354] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  438.401359] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[  438.404691] usb 2-2: cmd cmplt err -71
[  438.404695] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR Transfer event for disabled endpoint or incorrect stream ring
[  438.404698] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: @000000003fb70700 00000000 00000000 04000000 08078001
[  439.135787] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[  439.136027] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#0 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 1 inflight: CMD 
[  439.136036] sd 8:0:0:0: tag#0 CDB: Mode Sense(6) 1a 00 08 00 04 00
[  439.136109] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Asking for cache data failed
[  439.136119] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  439.363764] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  439.363767] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  439.483784] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  439.483787] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense not available.
[  439.723819] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  453.361652] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  453.378371] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  453.378373] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  453.378375] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  453.378376] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  453.378377] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: NA4AT906
[  453.380046] scsi host9: uas
[  453.380499] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  453.381082] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  453.381084] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  453.381695] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  453.842067] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  453.842071] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[  453.842272] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  453.853509]  sdb: sdb1
[  453.854847] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  501.001736] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  501.118525] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  501.153024] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  501.527014] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  501.543688] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  501.543690] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  501.543692] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  501.543693] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  501.543694] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: NA4AT906
[  501.545329] scsi host10: uas
[  501.546356] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  501.546876] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  501.547082] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  501.547085] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  501.547394] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  501.547397] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[  501.547554] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  503.618587]  sdb: sdb1
[  503.619863] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  513.448650] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  513.571824] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  513.604864] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  513.980307] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  513.996960] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=2321
[  513.996962] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  513.996964] usb 2-2: Product: Expansion
[  513.996965] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Seagate
[  513.996966] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: NA4AT906
[  513.998656] scsi host11: uas
[  513.999666] scsi 11:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Seagate  Expansion        0502 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  514.000116] sd 11:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  514.000871] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525167 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  514.000873] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  514.001488] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  514.001492] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[  514.001638] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  516.080393]  sdb: sdb1
[  516.081744] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  516.947836] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[  516.948257] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronizing SCSI cache
[  517.071106] sd 11:0:0:0: [sdb] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
```

This is quite lengthy and I truly appreciate if someone can read through the above to let me know the issue with the disk.

I have quite memorable as well as sensitive information, for me to attempt recovery from a professional firm and would like to do do it myself.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It seems the partitioning is recognized (`sdb: sdb1`), but there are errors reported. As this is supposed to be a NTFS partition, the error may be from being not correctly removed from Windows. You may try `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` and, if successful, `sudo fsck -V -n /dev/sdb1` (don't forget the `-n`, which says 'Just report, do nothing'). And append the output to your question.

Comment: Thanks Ridgy. Tried fdisk command as said above  and the output is :  
root@rescue-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-3rd:/home/rescue# fdisk -l /dev/sdb
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: No such device or address

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the ntfsfix command? Sometimes the disk is not properly exited on windows and you need to fix it before reading the disk

Comment: Thanks Dark Sinus. Output of Ntfsfix command :  root@rescue-ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-3rd:/home/rescue# ntfsfix /dev/sdb
Failed to determine whether /dev/sdb is mounted: No such file or directory
Mounting volume... Failed to access '/dev/sdb': No such file or directory
Error opening '/dev/sdb': No such file or directory
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Failed to access '/dev/sdb': No such file or directory
Failed to startup volume: No such file or directory. Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.    Can't run chkdsk as windows is not recognising the drive. Any further help pls

Answer (score 1):

If the disk is a 2" disk without external power supply ("Expansion Portable"), one reason might be that there is not enough power to spin up the disk when powered via USB, see message

```
[  180.177288] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  181.178895] ................................................................................
[  261.140098] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
```

Here an active powered USB HUB may help.

If it is powered by its own power supply ("Expansion Desktop"), it seems the disk is corrupt in some way. As this might be the SATA-to-USB controller as well, there is one more chance to get the data back if the disk itself is still working:

- Carefully open the case (might be there are screws hidden by rubber dampers)
- Carefully get the disk out of the case
- Get yourself a different SATA-to-USB-Adapter with own power supply and try with that
- Or better: If your PC has an unused SATA port, connect the disk there (plus power line) and try. In this case the tool `GSmartControl` may help, as SMART is supported by modern disks when connected via SATA (does mostly not work via USB).

SMART is a way to read information about the disk state and errors occured. Information on how to use `GSmartControl` see e.g. https://www.technibble.com/gsmartcontrol-monitor-test-hard-drive-smart-data/