# Extrernal HDD not suddenly recognised

Tags: xubuntu, usb-drive, external-hdd, 19.04

I have a Seagate 5tb external hard drive I use for storing various media.  Today, I plugged it into Xubuntu 19.4.  The drive made a few 'grating' sounds, the light indicating it is working came on, but Xubuntu cannot see the drive.

It does not register in Thunar, and `sudo fdisk -l` does not display it.

#### Update 01:

Changing the USB slot I use, and typing `sudo fdisk -l` again output the message:

```
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

#### Update 02:

Yesterday evening, `sudo fdisk -l` stopped reporting the presence of the external HDD.

Today, `sudo fdisk -l` hangs while trying to read the external HDD and I seem not to be able to end the task (`ctrl+c` does not exit).

However, Thunar sees the presence of the drives, but cannot seem to mount them.  I clicked on one of the partitions on the external HDD and now it is trying to mount, and so wont let me unmount either!

> pbhj

found another issue which looks like it might be a similar problem, but I am not sure what advice to follow in the link which pbhj provided.

#### Update 03:

If I plug the external HDD into a USB slot, then unplug it, it also appears that the USB slot gets 'turned off' by my laptop.  Plugging in a mouse shows the mouse does not work, and other USB drives do not work anymore in the drive.

Can anyone help in diagnosing this issue?

Comment: Maybe someone can help you, if you post the output of "dmesg".

Comment: I suspect something happened, probably corruption. If it has NTFS partition or partitions you may be able to correct it with Windows error correction tools.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for joining in.  The external HDD is  formatted to ext5.  Dmesg to follow -- it generated a lot of output!

Comment: Ok, I put the Dmesg into a pastebin, since there was a lot of it and I am not sure what's needed.  it can be found at:  [https://pastebin.com/6Z7vkL0U ]

Comment: Looks like a dupe of https://askubuntu.com/questions/862664/external-hdd-detected-but-not-recgnised-cannot-mount-cannot-format-cannot-do, same "DID_ERROR", etc.

Comment: Hi again.  A development:  The HDD worked for most of today, and then in the past hour I had to reboot my system, and no it is back to not being recognised at all (`sudo fdisk -l` does not report the HDD as connected).  I am not sure I understand what the potential dupe pbhj has identified for me wants me to do with the drive to potentially fix this problem.  Can someone suggest something specific I can run with please?